# Writing Unicode Characters to an OStream

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t, ostream

I'm working with unicode/wide characters and I'm trying to create a toString method ([Java ::toString equiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring)). Will ostream handle wide characters, if so is there a way to warn the consumer of the stream that it is unicode coming out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `ostream` nor the rest of C++ know anything about Unicode. Usually you write a string conversion in C++ as follows:

```
template<typename Char, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& stream, const YourType& object) {
    return stream << object.a << object.b;  // or whatever
}
```

Whether you get something Unicode-like is up to the implementation. Streams in C++ are never text streams in the sense of Java, and C++'s strings are not strings in the sense of Java. If you want a real Unicode string, you might want to have a look at the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Wide strings are non-portable and better be avoided in C++. They can be UTF-16, UTF-32 or even non-Unicode depending on platform.

The common approach in C++ is to use UTF-8 encoded multibyte `char` strings internally and, if necessary, do transcoding at system boundaries. Most modern systems such as Linux and macOS work well with UTF-8 so passing them to an output stream works. Windows is the most problematic because of legacy code pages. You can use [Boost Nowide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/nowide/doc/html/index.html) or [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) for portable UTF-8 output.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt}.