# How to convert from type (Class) to std:string?

Tags: c++, string, class, types, std

So I have an array of strings called blog[] and I'm trying to use a string from the array at position i, like:

```
outfile << blog[i];
```

But the problem is that blog[i] is of type MicroBlog (MicroBlog is a class I'm working with)

So my question is how can I convert from type MicroBlog to type string?

Here is the method I'm trying to use blog[i] in:

```
bool MicroBlog::SaveBlog(const string filename, const MicroBlog &AnotherMicroBlog)
{

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename.c_str());


    num_tweets = AnotherMicroBlog.num_tweets;
    for (int i=0; i < num_tweets; i++)                 
    {


                outfile << blog[i];             
        outfile.close();
        }             




}
```

Comment: you'll want your MicroBlog class to have a .toString() function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ equivalent of java.toString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring)

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a `std::string`, or do you want to stream it out to `outfile`?

Comment: The canonical way is to overload operator<<.

See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own operator ie `toString()` or overload `<<`:

```
 class Microblog {

     ....

     std::string toString() const { //public
          string ret = all_the_data;
          return ret;
     }
 };
```

And then `outfile << blog[i].toString();`

Comment: So I put that in my .h, and then what do I do to my code where I'm trying to use blog[i]? I've added my method I'm trying to use it in.

Comment: This? `outfile << blog[i].toString();`?