# inherit from std::string or operator overloading

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading

I want to have a class like below:

```
Class Test {
  Test();
  ~Test();
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to use following statement:

```
std::string str;
Test t;
str = t;
```

what should I do? should I override to_string? If yes it seems that it is not possible to inherit from std::string class.
Or I have to override special operator?
What about Pointer assignment? like below:

```
std::string str;
Test* t = new Test();
str = t;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a user-defined conversion operator to `std::string`:

```
class Test {
  //...
public:
  operator std::string () const {
    return /*something*/;
  }
};
```

This will allow a `Test` object to be implicitly-converted to a `std::string`.

Comment: `Test::operator std::string() const` just my 2c

Comment: what should I do If I want to assign pointer of Test class to std::string?

Comment: I'd recommend you don't. Or do this: `std::string tmp = my_test; doSomething(&tmp);`

Comment: I need to. I did not get your last comment answer. I have a pointer of my Test Class and I need to assign it to a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432898/assign-a-class-pointer-to-stdstring-in-c

Comment: @JGC Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you meant assigning a `Test*` to a `std::string*`, not a `Test*` to a `std::string`. `str = *t;` should work fine if you have the above operator.

Comment: @TartanLlama I can not add * before pointers because of reasons. Is it possible to do other thing?

Comment: @JGC Can you write a function to do the indirection for you?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have solved it using above answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although in C++ it is possible, it is generally not advised to inherit from standard classes, see [Why should one not derive from c++ std string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006860/why-should-one-not-derive-from-c-std-string-class) for more info.

I am wondering, what is the function of the assignment of

```
str = t;
```

str is a std::string type, t is Test type. So what is the expected value of the assigment? No one can guess. I suggest to explicitly call a conversion method or an operator for code clarity.

This would make your example look like:

```
str = t.convertToString();
```

or the more standard way is to implement the stream operator, which makes

```
str << t;
```

(Note this example works if str is a stream type, if it is a string, you need further code, see [C++ equivalent of java.toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring).)

But, if you really want it to work without a conversion method, you can override the string assignment operator of Test:

```
class Test {
public:
    operator std::string() const { return "Hi"; }
}
```

See also [toString override in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171739/tostring-override-in-c)

Although this is a perfect solution to your question, it may come with unforeseen problems on the long run, as detailed in the linked article.

Comment: you can make conversion operators explicit in C++11, so you'd have to write `str = static_cast<std::string>(t);` which is probably safer, even if it is more characters.

Comment: Note that some std classes are intended for inheritance, like e.g. the std exception classes. But most are not.